# Android gridview not responive

Tags: android, gridview, layout, grid

I've been developing a Point of Sale application for waiters so they don't have to write the orders down but they can actually go directly through the cloud to the checkout.

Anyway I have been struggling with a Grid which I want to be responsive for all the HDPI phones/machines. Which is not really working out at the moment.

This is the code atm:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/logon_bg" >

<GridLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:columnCount="6"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:rowCount="10" >

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/sp02"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


         <Spinner
             android:layout_margin="4dp"
             android:layout_row="0"
             android:layout_column="1"
             android:layout_columnSpan="2"
             android:id="@+id/sp01"
             android:layout_width="116dp"
             android:layout_height="44dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_blue"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt03"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_red"
         android:text="5"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt04"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_white"
         android:textColor="#000000" />


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt11"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="1"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt12"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="1"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt13"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="1"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt14"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="1"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt20"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="2"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
         android:ellipsize="marquee"/>"

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt21"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="2"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt22"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="2"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt23"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="2"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt24"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="2"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt30"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="3"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt31"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="3"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt32"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="3"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt33"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="3"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt34"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="3"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt40"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="4"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt41"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="4"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt42"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="4"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt43"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="4"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt44"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="4"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt50"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="5"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt51"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="5"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt52"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="5"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt53"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="5"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt54"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="5"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt60"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="6"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt61"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="6"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt62"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="6"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt63"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="6"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt64"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="6"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt70"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="7"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt71"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="7"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt72"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="7"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt73"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="7"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt74"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="7"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt80"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="8"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt81"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="8"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt82"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="8"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt83"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="8"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt84"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="4"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="8"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/sp03"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="9"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_orange"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt91"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_columnSpan="2"
         android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="9"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_trans"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt92"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="3"
         android:layout_columnSpan="2"
         android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="9"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation_trans"
         android:text="Selectie Toevoegen"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt10"
         android:layout_width="54dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_row="1"
         android:background="@drawable/button_workstation"
         android:text="Klein Broodje Rosbief"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textSize="15sp" />

 </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which fits fine for 480x800 but not for 1080x1920.

All help is really appreciated!

**EDIT:**
After deleting the RelativeLayout and editing: android:columnCount="5" I get this. I want it to fill the full screen.

[Image link](http://ctnr.be/printscreen.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the attributes of your grid to `match_parent`

```
<GridLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" ...
```

Instead of:

```
<GridLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. It is still not responsive as it strechtes the lines between the last row and column.